# How do you create a constructor that takes an array of "Range" objects and initializes the list, list is intialized to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor

I am having trouble creating a constructor that takes an array of Range objects and initializes the list – list should be initialized to an ArrayList of Range. This is the code I have so far from my classes. This constructor method I am trying to create belongs in the multipleGroups Method. I have searched through stackoverflow with no luck for any similar questions but had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
public interface NumberGroup
{
  boolean contains(int value);
}


import java.util.Scanner
public class Range implements NumberGroup
{
  private int minValue, maxValue;

  public Range(int minValue, int maxValue)
  {
    this.minValue = minValue;
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
  }

  public boolean contains(int value)
  {
    return minValue <= value && value <= maxValue;
  }
}

import java.util.List
import java.util.ArrayList
public class MultipleGroups implements NumberGroup
{
private List<NumberGroup> groupList;

//problem area here.
public MultipleGroups(){

}

public boolean contains(int num)
{
  for(NumberGroup group : groupList)
    if(group.contains(num))
      return true;

  return false;
}

the test class tests the constructor with the following:
Range [] myRanges = new Range[3];
myRanges[0] = new Range(5,8);
myRanges[1] = new Range(10,12);
myRanges[2] new Range(1, 6);
group = new MultipleGroups(myRanges);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following appears to satisfy your requirements:

```
public MultipleGroups(Range[] ranges){
  this.groupList = Arrays.asList(ranges);
}
```

---

There are a few things you might consider doing rather than just using this as-is:

You may want to allow varargs invocation (i.e. that you don't have to explicitly create the array at the call site):

```
public MultipleGroups(Range... ranges){
```

and you may want to copy the list in order to avoid callers doing nefarious things to the array after they call the constructor:

```
  this.groupList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ranges));
```

Comment: Thank you, that passed my testing class. The way the instructions for the constructor are worded confused me: "A constructor that takes an array of Range objects and initializes the list – list should be
initialized to an ArrayList of Range"

Comment: I'm trying to break down the instructions to understand them better and how you figured that out. So the constructor needs an argument of array named Ranges, then the list is to be converted into an arrayList? I'm fairly new to all this.